How to mock the results for two open file calls in one class function
The class:
class ABC(object):
  def __init__(self, files):
    self.store = []
    self.parse_files(files)

  def parse_files(self, files):
    for filename in files:
      with open(filename, newline="") as f:
        self.store.append(f.read())

The test:
from unittest.mock import Mock, mock_open, patch

class TestABC:
  result1 = 'string1'
  result2 = 'string2'
  result = Mock()
  result.side_effect = [result1, result2]

  @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data=result())
  def test_parse_files(self, a):
    item = ABC(['foo', 'bar'])
    assert item.store == ['string1', 'string2']

But item.store == ['string1', 'string1']
I thought the open would return result1 and result2 since result() is iter?

The problem is that read_data of mock_open won't work with side_effect that way, because it is expected to be a stream, not a mock.
The easiest way to do this is probably to use your own standard mock for open, and use the side_effect on the read function mock:
class TestABC:
    @patch("builtins.open")
    def test_parse_files(self, mocked_open):
        mocked_open().__enter__().read.side_effect = ['string1', 'string2']
        item = ABC(['foo', 'bar'])
        assert item.store == ['string1', 'string2']

As open is called with the context manager, you need to add __enter__ (called internally by the context manager) to get the mocked file.
The rest is just standard mocking of the return value of read by using side_effect.

I see and thank you, I know in my example I did f.read() which you mocked with read.side_effect. What if I am passing f to like this csv.DictReader(f), how can I make sure csv.Dictreader(f) would read the right string?

You have to patch DictReader accordingly, depending on how you use it (or use something like pyfakefs to mock the whole filesystem). Please adapt the question, or write a new one to make clear what you really need.
